# Black Screen - ELD Buf Size of 0, force 128

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, hdmi

yesterday an update came up on my Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit). Kernel and some other stuff. I've installed the update, but didn't reboot quite than because I've planned to shutdown my PC anyways an hour later.
So today, I was booting the PC, choosing my Ubuntu. I was prompted for my password, all normal, but then only a black screen. With "System error" pop-up in the top left, asking me to report it (but nothing happened when I clicked the button).

So I've changed the runlevel (i guess that's what it's called? The ctrl alt F3/... combi), logged in, asked dmesg what's up and it told me:

HDMI: ELD buf size of 0, force 128.

I've checked for updates, another kernel update or something that might fix this in the repos but I could not find anything. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did solve this by installing `fglrx-amdcccle-updates` from repository. Had the latest driver for my AMD gfx card installed manually. Seems like some configuration went wrong/missing/broken..